# How to generate parameters.yml to parameters.yml.dist without composer install/update

Tags: composer-php, symfony

I have a question. I want to know is there any alternate ways to generate parameters.yml to parameters.yml.dist without composer install/update. During composer install/update the file is generated and overwritten respectively. But I'm looking to do without going through composer. I wonder is there any symfony console commands to achieve this. Anyone has answer?

Comment: its a bit unclear what youre asking. What do you mean by 'generate parameters.yml *to* parameters.yml.dist'? Do you mean 'from'?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can just run `composer run-script post-install-cmd`

It will probably run some other scripts though (in default symfony configuration operate with cache, bootstrap and so on).

If you want to **only** build parameteres, make a new section in your composer/scripts section. Like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "build-params": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters"
    ]
},
...
```

and then just run `composer run-script build-params`

Comment: @Dmirty Malyshenko. You are awesome. This is what I wanted exactly. Thanks.